# Do I need to cast to unsigned char before calling toupper(), tolower(), et al.?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, toupper, tolower

A while ago, someone with high reputation here on Stack Overflow wrote in a comment that it is necessary to cast a `char`-argument to `unsigned char` before calling `std::toupper` and `std::tolower` (and similar functions).

On the other hand, Bjarne Stroustrup does not mention the need to do so in *the C++ Programming Language*.  He just uses `toupper` like

> ```
> string name = "Niels Stroustrup";
>
> void m3() {
>   string s = name.substr(6,10);  // s = "Stroustr up"
>   name.replace(0,5,"nicholas");  // name becomes "nicholas Stroustrup"
>   name[0] = toupper(name[0]);   // name becomes "Nicholas Stroustrup"
> }
> ```

(Quoted from said book, 4th edition.)

[The reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper) says that the input needs to be representable as `unsigned char`.
For me this sounds like it holds for every `char` since `char` and `unsigned char` have the same size.

So is this cast unnecessary or was Stroustrup careless?

Edit: The [libstdc++ manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/strings.html) mentions that the input character must be from the [basic source character set](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r12/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r12.cbclx01/charset.htm), but does not cast. I guess this is covered by @Keith Thompson's reply, they all have a positive representation as `signed char` and `unsigned char`?

Comment: It would be nice if you could post a link to the comment, if possible.

Comment: [You may find this an interesting read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029840/convert-char-to-int-in-c-and-c/5031906#5031906), one of the top-hits from `[c] toupper cast`.

Comment: @dyp http://stackoverflow.com/a/20182481/3002139

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes, the argument to `toupper` needs to be converted to `unsigned char` to avoid the risk of undefined behavior.

The types `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` are three distinct types. `char` has the same range and representation as *either* `signed char` *or* `unsigned char`. (Plain `char` is very commonly signed and able to represent values in the range -128..+127.)

The `toupper` function takes an `int` argument and returns an `int` result. Quoting the C standard, section 7.4 paragraph 1:

> In all cases the argument is an **`int`**, the value of which shall be
> representable as an **`unsigned char`** or shall equal the value of
> the macro **`EOF`** . If the argument has any other value, the
> behavior is undefined.

(C++ incorporates most of the C standard library, and defers its definition to the C standard.)

The `[]` indexing operator on `std::string` returns a reference to `char`. If plain `char` is a signed type, and if the value of `name[0]` happens to be negative, then the expression

```
toupper(name[0])
```

has undefined behavior.

The language guarantees that, even if plain `char` is signed, all members of the basic character set have non-negative values, so given the initialization

```
string name = "Niels Stroustrup";
```

the program doesn't risk undefined behavior. But yes, in general a `char` value passed to `toupper` (or to any of the functions declared in `<cctype>` / `<ctype.h>`) needs to be converted to `unsigned char`, so that the implicit conversion to `int` won't yield a negative value and cause undefined behavior.

The `<ctype.h>` functions are commonly implemented using a lookup table. Something like:

```
// assume plain char is signed
char c = -2;
c = toupper(c); // undefined behavior
```

may index outside the bounds of that table.

Note that converting to `unsigned`:

```
char c = -2;
c = toupper((unsigned)c); // undefined behavior
```

doesn't avoid the problem. If `int` is 32 bits, converting the `char` value `-2` to `unsigned` yields `4294967294`. This is then implicitly converted to `int` (the parameter type), which *probably* yields `-2`.

`toupper` *can* be implemented so it behaves sensibly for negative values (accepting all values from `CHAR_MIN` to `UCHAR_MAX`), but it's not required to do so. Furthermore, the functions in `<ctype.h>` are required to accept an argument with the value `EOF`, which is typically `-1`.

The C++ standard makes adjustments to some C standard library functions. For example, `strchr` and several other functions are replaced by overloaded versions that enforce `const` correctness. There are no such adjustments for the functions declared in `<cctype>`.

Comment: I've given you a +1 cause the answer is good. But why are you quoting from the C standard in a C++ question?

Comment: @JonathanMee: Good question. It's because C++ inherits most of C's standard library and defers its definition to the C standard.

Comment: I may have gotten impatient waiting for a response and opened a new question. I thought I should link it here in full disclosure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37614714/what-is-the-relationship-between-the-c-and-c-standards Feel free to chime in.

Comment: The conversion back from `int` to `char` is implementation defined, isn't it?

Comment: @L.F.: Only if the value is outside the range of `char`, which it almost certainly won't be given that the argument was a `char` value.

Comment: @KeithThompson I mean, suppose that `char` is signed and the value is -42.  Then it is converted to `unsigned char` (213), and to `int` (213).  Now isn't the result of `(char) 213` implementation defined?

Comment: @L.F.: Yes, good point! (BTW, it's 214, not 213.) Or it can raise an implementation-defined signal, though I don't think any implementation does that. In practice, it's unlikely to cause any problems.

Comment: A minor point - you said "The [] indexing operator on std::string returns a char value." which is inaccurate. The `[]` operator returns a reference to char, not a char value.

Comment: @aafulei Fixed, thanks.

Comment: I love this answer, and will personally be citing it when I see this bug (as we do), but it'd be even better if there were more emphasis on the erroneousness of an `unsigned` cast, since your answer kinda reads as the first paragraph and then some will look for something to copy/paste... They may see `c = toupper((unsigned)c);` and think this is the ultimate solution. I'd suggest a nice, clear title for each of **the wrong ways**, and then another clear title for **the right way** using `c = tolower((unsigned char) c);` as the example.

Answer (score 5):

The reference is referring to the value being *representable* as an `unsigned char`, not to it *being* an `unsigned char`. That is, the behavior is undefined if the actual value is not between 0 and `UCHAR_MAX`  (typically 255). (Or `EOF`, which is basically the reason it takes an `int` instead of a `char`.)

Comment: As the parameter of `toupper` is an `int`, I think negative `char` values could cause UB. Any conversion from `int` to `unsigned char` happens internally in the function.

Comment: Nobody said that an `unsigned char` cannot represent values greater than 255.

Comment: @dyp "Any conversion from `int` to `unsigned char` happens internally in the function." --> Not quite as that may convert `EOF` to 255.  _After_ coping with `EOF`, conversion to `unsigned char` would be reasonable, yet that behavior is not specified.

Answer (score 3):

In C, `toupper` (and many other functions) take `int`s even though you'd expect them to take `char`s.  Additionally, `char` is signed on some platforms and unsigned on others.

The advice to cast to `unsigned char` before calling `toupper` is correct for C.  <strike>I don't think it's needed in C++, provided you pass it an `int` that's in range.</strike>  I can't find anything specific to whether it's needed in C++.

If you want to sidestep the issue, use the [`toupper` defined in `<locale>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/toupper).  It's a template, and takes any acceptable character type.  You also have to pass it a `std::locale`.  If you don't have any idea which locale to choose, use `std::locale("")`, which is supposed to be the user's preferred locale:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <locale>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string name("Bjarne Stroustrup");
    std::string uppercase;

    std::locale loc("");

    std::transform(name.begin(), name.end(), std::back_inserter(uppercase),
                   [&loc](char c) { return std::toupper(c, loc); });

    std::cout << name << '\n' << uppercase << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's correct for C. Why do you think the same thing doesn't apply to C++?

Comment: Its not needed in C either if you pass it an `int` in the first place. It *is* needed if you are passing a `char` in *either*.

Comment: @KeithThompson I haven't checked the Standard, but frankly the reason I don't think the cast is needed for C++ is simply that I've only ever seen the advice to cast in C projects. It's possible that I simply haven't read the right articles, but I find it interesting that I've never seen a C++ expert mention the need for a cast while I have seen C experts mention it.

Comment: C++ includes most of the C standard library by reference (C++11 refers to the C99 library, but `<ctype.h>` hasn't changed much, if at all, from C90 to C99 to C11). There are a few cases where C++ makes changes to the C standard library, but I see no mention of any such changes to `<ctype.h>`. I think the C++ experts are just missing something. (`toupper(c)` is "safe" if its argument is known to be in the basic character set.)

Answer (score 1):

Sadly Stroustrup was careless :-(
And yes, latin letters codes should be non-negative (and no cast are required)...
Some implementations correctly works without casting to unsigned char...
By the some experience, it may cost a several hours to find the cause of segfault of a such toupper (when it is known that a segfault are there)...
And there are also isupper, islower etc

Comment: Arguably, care*ful* - the example in the question uses only characters in the source character set.  They are guaranteed to work whether `char` is signed or unsigned.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of casting the argument as unsigned char, you can cast the function. You will need to include *functional* header. Here's a sample code:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    typedef unsigned char BYTE; // just in case

    std::string name("Daniel Brühl"); // used this name for its non-ascii character!

    std::transform(name.begin(), name.end(), name.begin(),
            (std::function<int(BYTE)>)::toupper);

    std::cout << "uppercase name: " << name << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
uppercase name: DANIEL BRüHL
```

As expected, toupper has no effect on non-ascii characters. But this casting is beneficial for avoiding unexpected behavior.

Comment: That seems to work, but it seems rather convoluted. How is it better than casting the argument?

Comment: @KeithThompson Note that the function `toupper` is passed as lambda expression. So in this case, it may be better to cast the function.

Comment: "As expected, toupper has no effect on non-ascii characters" --> certainly a _locale_ issue.