# Check if the input is a number or string in C++

Tags: c++, string, integer, user-input, string-conversion

I wrote the following code to check whether the input(answer3) is a number or string, if it is not a number it should return "Enter Numbers Only" but it returns the same even for numbers. Please suggest me a solution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std; 
int main ()
{

string ques1= "Client's Name :";
string ques2 = "Client's Address :";
string ques3 = "Mobile Number :";

char answer1 [80];
string answer2;
int answer3;

     cout<<ques1<<endl;    
     cin>>answer1;      

     cout<<ques2<<endl;    
     cin>>answer2; 

     cout<<ques3<<endl;
     cin>>answer3;

       if (isdigit(answer3))
       {
              cout<<"Correct"<<endl;     

              }

        else
        {
          cout<<"Enter Numbers Only"<<endl;  

            }

 system("pause>null");
 return 0;  

}
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with the enter key on your keyboard? The spacebar seems dodgy as well

Comment: `isdigit` takes a single character as an `int`, interprets it as an ASCII character, and returns nonzero if it's a digit character ('0' through '9', ASCII 48 through 57) or zero if it's not. It has no way to tell you if you read an integer into `answer3`.

Comment: Further, `cin >> someIntVariable` discards leading whitespace, reads an optional sign (`-` or `+`) followed by a sequence of digits, stopping at the first non-digit character. So if someone enters something that can't be interpreted, it sets the variable to 0. Which is why `isdigit` later fails.

Comment: It makes no sense to call `isdigit` on an `integer` unless you know *precisely* what it means for an integer to *be* a digit.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `regex` to do this:

```
#include <regex>

bool isNumber(std::string x){
    std::regex e ("^-?\\d+");
    if (std::regex_match (x,e)) return true;
    else return false;}
```

If you want to make `isNumber()` a generic function which can take any type of input:

```
#include <regex>
#include <sstream>

template<typename T>
bool isNumber(T x){
    std::string s;
    std::regex e ("^-?\\d+");
    std::stringstream ss; 
    ss << x;
    ss >>s;
    if (std::regex_match (s,e)) return true;
    else return false;}
```

The above `isNumber()` function checks for integer only, double or float value with precision (which contains dot `.`) will not return true.
If you want precision too, then change the `regex` line to:

```
std::regex e ("^-?\\d*\\.?\\d+");
```

If you want a more efficient solution, see [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33894544/3744681).

Answer (score 7):

**If you're using C++98**, you can use `stringstreams` (`#include <sstream>`):

```
std::string s = "1234798797";
std::istringstream iss(s);

int num = 0;

if (!(iss >> num).fail()) {
    std::cout << num << std::endl;
}
else {
    std::cerr << "There was a problem converting the string to an integer!" << std::endl;
}
```

**If boost is available to you**, you can use [lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm) (`#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>`):

```
std::string s = "1234798797";
int num = boost::lexical_cast<int>(si);//num is 1234798797
std::cout << num << std::endl;
```

**If C++11 is available to you**, you can use the builtin `std::stoi` [function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) from `<string>`:

```
std::string s = "1234798797";
int mynum = std::stoi(s);
std::cout << mynum << std::endl;
```

OUTPUTS:

```
1234798797
```

Answer (score 4):

The function **isdigit()** is used to test for only single digits ( 0,1,...,9)

Use this function to check for positive integers (and zero):

```
bool is_nonnegative_integer(const std::string& s)
{
    std::string::const_iterator it = s.begin();
    while (it != s.end() && std::isdigit(*it)) ++it;
    return !s.empty() && it == s.end();
}
```

Comment: This can't be used for decimal numbers. Only integers can be checked.

Comment: @jrd1: no pun intended :)

Answer (score 2):

The input to `isdigit` is an integer value. However, it will return true (non-zero) only if the value corresponds to '0'-'9'. If you convert them to integer values, they are 48-57. For all other values, `isdigit` will return false (zero).

You can check whether you got an integer by changing checking logic:

```
if ( cin.fail() )
{
   cout<<"Correct"<<endl;     
}
else
{
   cout<<"Enter Numbers Only"<<endl;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another answer using [`strtod`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtod/):

```
bool isNumber(const std::string& s){
   if(s.empty() || std::isspace(s[0]) || std::isalpha(s[0])) return false ;
   char * p ;
   strtod(s.c_str(), &p) ;
   return (*p == 0) ;
}
```

To be able to handle any type of parameter use template:

```
#include <sstream>

template<typename T>
bool isNumber(T x){
   std::string s;
   std::stringstream ss; 
   ss << x;
   ss >>s;
   if(s.empty() || std::isspace(s[0]) || std::isalpha(s[0])) return false ;
   char * p ;
   strtod(s.c_str(), &p) ;
   return (*p == 0) ;
}
```

---

**Note:**

1. White space will make it return false.
2. `NAN` and `INF` will make it return false (to be exact, any character except valid exponent will make it return false). If you want to allow `nan` and `inf`, delete the `|| std::isalpha(s[0])` part.
3. scientific form is allowed i.e 1e+12 will return true.
4. Double/float or integer will return true.
5. This is more efficient than the [regex answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31238989/3744681). (regex is heavy).

Answer (score 0):

The interest phenomenon are the `isdigit` requires `char` to be cast to `unsigned char`. (Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805674/do-i-need-to-cast-to-unsigned-char-before-calling-toupper)).

Answer (score 0):

This is a somewhat old question, but I figured I'd add my own solution that I'm using in my code.

Another way to check if a string is a number is the `std::stod` function, which has been mentioned, but I use it a bit differently. In my use case, I use a try-catch block to check if the input is a string or number, like so with your code:

```
...
try {
    double n = stod(answer3);
    //This will only be reached if the number was converted properly.
    cout << "Correct" << endl;
} catch (invalid_argument &ex) {
    cout << "Enter Numbers Only" << endl;
}
...
```

The primary problem with this solution is that strings that begin with numbers (but aren't all numbers) *will* be converted to numbers. This can be easily fixed by using `std::to_string` on the returned number and comparing it to the original string.