# How can I see if a char is equal to anything but a letter in c++?

Tags: c++, char

```
if( !( *it >= 0x41 || *it <= 0x5A ) && !( *it >= 0x61 || *it <= 0x7A ) )
```

I tried something like this but it doesn't catch anything.

Comment: Try [isalpha()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/) (`!isalpha()` in your case)

Comment: Are you sure `0x41` to `0x5A` *is* equal to a letter? (There are other ways to *be* sure.)

Comment: If you're interested in characters with a particular character value, (i.e. a particular letter of the alphabet), then use character literals (i.e. `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'`, etc...) , not numeric codes, unless you are trying to obfuscate your code.

Answer (score 2):

There is the standard library function [`std::isalpha`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha) for this:

```
if( !std::isalpha(static_cast<unsigned_char>(*it))
```

It tests if a character is a letter or not. Note that the cast before calling `std::isalpha` [is indeed needed.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805674/do-i-need-to-cast-to-unsigned-char-before-calling-toupper)

Comment: An alternative is `std::isalpha(*it, std::locale());` which checks a `char` in the default locale.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the expression

```
*it >= 0x41 || *it <= 0x5A
```

This expression is `true` for any value at all. Consider a simpler version:

```
x > 5 || x < 10
```

Every value `x` is either greater than 5 or less than 10 (or both). There's no value for which neither of those tests are true.

You probably want

```
*it >= 0x41 && *it <= 0x5A
```

which checks whether your character is *both* greater than 'A' and less than 'Z'. You'll have to make similar changes to the other parts of your test, too.

Of course, a better way is to use the standard `isalpha()` function, but changing to use that won't help you learn anything about why your given code doesn't work.