# Transforming a string to lowercase in a new string

Tags: c++

Converting a string can be done with

```
std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), ::toupper);
```

but what's the best way to transform it into a new modified copy ?

tried :

```
string s1="text",s2;
std::transform(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(), ::toupper);
```

but it fails at runtime with "Segmentation fault"

I managed to do it by  :

```
string s1="text",s2;
s2 = s1;
std::transform(s2.begin(), s2.end(), s2.begin(), ::toupper);
```

and of course you can create a function to go char by char, but I don't think that's optimal, and I'm not learning anything from this...

Comment: You need `std::back_inserter()`.

Comment: You should be using `std::toupper` and ensuring that negative values are not passed into it if `char` is signed, lest you have undefined behaviour.

Comment: @chris the example was actualy copy-pasted from the [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) site, 
so can std::string have unsigned char or negative values ?

Comment: @Columbo why did you remove your answer ?

Comment: @clickstefan Because I didn't like it. I post answers to help and didn't consider it helpful yet.

Comment: @clickstefan, Yes, if `char` is signed, then `std::string` can certainly contain negative values unless you have a guarantee otherwise. And I did mean signed, not unsigned, sorry. Thought I fixed that quickly enough, but maybe not :/

Comment: @chris can you give a small example (sorry c/c++ rookie here)

Comment: @clickstefan, I'd prefer the range-based for loop in the answer, but it's easily possible with a lambda (`[](unsigned char c) {return std::toupper(c);}`) or a function that looks the same.

Comment: @clickstefan `sorry c/c++ rookie here`  Well, I applaud you for using `std::transform` right off the bat, unlike other rookies.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yeah... but now it seems I have some code to remake :)
I like c++, compared to c, but sometimes there are too many methods to get to the same thing, and it's hard to spot the good from the bad.

Comment: someone posted an answer but I didn't get to comment :
what's the difference between `s1{"text"}` and s1="text"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::transform` doesn't know containers and will not insert new elements for you. 
[`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) provides an iterator that `push_back`s assigned values:

```
// DO NOT use this
std::transform(s1.begin(), s1.end(), std::back_inserter(s2), ::toupper);
//                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

However, you should not use the global version of `toupper` since it's deprecated. 
Also you [have to cast the argument to `unsigned char`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805674/do-i-need-to-cast-to-unsigned-char-before-calling-toupper) first, or undefined behavior is easily encountered.

`transform` does not seem to fit here as you would need a lambda; use

```
for (auto ch : s1)
    s2 += std::toupper((unsigned char)ch);
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2ebdad3004c48c7a).

Comment: so the lambda use would be needed for the `unsigned char` problem ?
so this makes 
`transform(str->begin(), str->end(), str->begin(), ::tolower);` invalid also ?

Comment: @clickstefan A lambda would be needed to call `std::tolower` in the first place. And yes, the line with `transform` would be invalid. The problem is that simply calling (the non-local version of) `tolower` with `char` is generally wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Unless use of `std::transform` is a requirement, you can use:

```
string s1="text";
string s2 = s1;
for ( auto& ch : s2 )
   ch = toupper((unsigned char)ch);
```

Comment: Oh, I totally overlooked that your loop is different than mine :) Anyway, the code still lacks the cast.

Comment: I don't understand the need for casting. `std::toupper()` takes an `int` as an input.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805674/do-i-need-to-cast-to-unsigned-char-before-calling-toupper

Comment: std::transform is not a must, but this still creates a copy of s1 before the actual conversion

Answer (score 0):

I do not quite understand why one of the answers says

> ```
> // DO NOT use this
> std::transform(s1.begin(), s1.end(), std::back_inserter(s2), ::toupper);
> //                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

[`push_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/push_back) is a method of `std::string` and it is perfectly fine to use [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) with [`std::back_inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter)

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string s1 = "ABCDEFG";
  std::string s2;
  std::transform(s1.begin(), s1.end(), std::back_inserter(s2),
                 [](unsigned char uc) { return std::tolower(uc); });
  std::cout << s2 << std::endl; // abcdefg
  return 0;
}
```