# Read number of whitespaces for an array of characters

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have to make a simple function to display the number of whitespaces in a predefined array of characters. 
This is my code : (please ignore the first part, only last part and whitespaces function)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int whitespaces(char[]);

void main(){
    char a[] = "Array of characters for test\n";  //Simple array of characters
    cout << "\n This is a test : " << a;
    char b[] = "\n\t Another array of character for test\n"; //Simple array with some escape sequences, \t and \n
    cout << "\n This is a test for usage of escape sequences : " << b;
    char c[] = "T E S T\n";                                   //Simple array with 8 characters and whitespaces
    cout << "\n Last test for whitespaces : "<<c;
    int ws = whitespaces(c);
    cout << "\n Number of whitespaces for the last array of characters is : "<<ws;
    _getch();
}

int whitespaces(char c[]){
    int count = 0;
    for (int n = 0; n <= sizeof(c); n++) {
        if (c[n] == ' '){
            count++;
        }
    }
        return(count);
}
```

Using Visual Studio express

Comment: .. and what precisely is the problem?

Comment: Right now, you're only looking for a literal space character. If you want to count all white space (e.g., also tabs and new-lines) you probably want to look up `isspace`.

Comment: `sizeof(c)` is the size of a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use standard C function `std::strlen` declared in header `<cstring>`  instead of `sizeof` operator because an array passed by value to a function is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element. Also the blank character is not the only white space character. Either you should use standard function `std::isspace`  or `std::isblank` declared in header `<cctype>`

So the function will look like

```
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>

//...

int whitespaces( const char c[] )
{
    int count = 0;
    size_t n = std::strlen( c );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
    {
        if ( std::isspace( c[i] ) ) ++count;
    }

    return ( count );
}
```

The other way is to use the characteristic of character arrays that store strings that they have the terminating zero.

In this case the function could be defined as

```
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>

//...

int whitespaces( const char c[] )
{
    int count = 0;

    while ( *c )
    {
        if ( std::isspace( *c++ ) ) ++count;
    }

    return ( count );
}
```

Also take into account that there are standard algorithms `std::count` and `std::count_if` that can be used instead of your function.

Comment: Your examples are both wrong. Not only because you forgot to dereference the pointer in one.

Comment: @Columbo It was a typo, Thanks. And what wrong with examples? Maybe you want to say that instead of int there must be used size_t?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow No, you lack a cast to `unsigned char`. See my answer.

Comment: @Columbo Why should the argument of isspace be casted to unsigned char?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow See the link in my answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805674/do-i-need-to-cast-to-unsigned-char-before-calling-toupper

Comment: @VladfromMoscow No, it's not. What do you mean? Have you read the reference for `isspace`?

Comment: @Columbo  He uses the basic character set where all symbols are non-negative.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow ... so you wrote a general function that only works with the sample inputs provided in the question?

Comment: @Columbo  In fact so. But you are right in general case you need casting. Though if you use a locale then the first parameter of isspace is defined as char.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what you can use if you want all whitespace characters to be counted (not only the space character):

```
std::string::size_type countWs( std::string const& str )
{
    return std::count_if( std::begin(str), std::end(str),
                          [] (unsigned char c) {return std::isspace(c);} );
}
```

Or, alternatively,

```
std::size_t countWs( char const* str )
{
    std::size_t c = 0;
    while (*str)
        c += !!std::isspace((unsigned char)*str++);
    return c;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1a2935b7fe0e617a). As to the casts to `unsigned char`, [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805674/do-i-need-to-cast-to-unsigned-char-before-calling-toupper) might be worth looking at.