# toupper tolower not working , help what's wrong with my code

Tags: c++, for-loop, tolower, toupper

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Module2.h"

int main()
{
std::cout<<"This is a test of Module2.h"<<std::endl;
std::cout<<UCase("This is a test of UCase")<<std::endl;
std::cout<<LCase("This is a test of LCase")<<std::endl;
system("pause");
return 0;

}
```

Module2.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Module2.h"

int main()
{
std::cout<<"This is a test of Module2.h"<<std::endl;
std::cout<<UCase("This is a test of UCase")<<std::endl;
std::cout<<LCase("This is a test of LCase")<<std::endl;
system("pause");
return 0;

}
```

Module2.cpp

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Module : Module2.cpp
//
//Purpose : Shows the usage of modular functions
///////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include "Module2.h"

///////////////////////////////////////////////////
//UCase()

char *UCase(char *str)
{
//convert each char in  the string to uppercase
//
int len = strlen(str);
for ( int i ; i < len ; i++)
{
    std::cout<<"In UCase"<<std::endl;
     str[i]=toupper(str[i]);
}

return str;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////
//LCase()

char *LCase(char *str)
{
//convert each char in  the string to uppercase
//
int len = strlen(str);
for ( int i ; i < len ; i++)
{
    std::cout<<"In LCase"<<std::endl;
    str[i]=tolower(str[i]);
}  
return str;
}
```

When I run it there is no warning or error .
But , it don't upper and lower the string .
I have thought my for loops are wrong , but it seems to be right .
What's wrong with my code.

Comment: If this compiled without warnings, you need to enable more warnings.

Comment: Are you sure your "Module2.h" is really what you posted, identical to "main.cpp"?

Comment: You have two main() functions. Only one is allowed: this is where the program is supposed to start

Comment: how to enable more warnings

Comment: @goInDoor Depends on the compiler. For gcc or clang, add the option -Wall

Comment: Also, is there a specific reason for not using std::string ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you are trying to modify string literals such as `"This is a test of UCase"`. This is *undefined behaviour*. You need to copy the literals into a `char` array that you can modify.

Also note that binding `char*` to a string literal is deprecated and forbidden, for good reason. This should have emitted a warning:

```
UCase("This is a test of UCase") // not good: binding char* to literal
```

There are other problems with your code: *undefined behaviour* (UB) in loops with uninitialized variables,

```
for ( int i ; i < len ; i++) // using uninitialized i: UB
```

You should also have a look at `toupper` and `tolower` documentation. They both accept `int` with some restrictions on their values. You have to ensure you don't pass a value that causes *undefined behaviour*, bearing in mind that `char` can be signed. See for example [*Do I need to cast to unsigned char before calling `toupper`?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805674/do-i-need-to-cast-to-unsigned-char-before-calling-toupper)

Comment: And anyway, `tolower` and `toupper` aren't really suitable for changing case. Only nearly, under some locales.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I added something about other problems in the code. Not sure it is worth spending the time on this crap.

Answer (score 1):

Loops like this one have undefined behavior:

```
for ( int i ; i < len ; i++)
```

The reason is that you did not start `i` at value `0`.
You have no idea what value `i` starts at!
It could be `-10`, could be `824`.

If you want a value to be initialized, ***you*** have to initialize it.
I suggest:

```
for (int i=0; i < len; i++)
```

Comment: for(int i=0 ; i<len ; i++) will lead it crash

Comment: @goInDoor The idea is that you fix *all the errors*.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *UCase( char *str)
{
char ch;
int i=0;

while(str[i])
{
    ch=str[i];
    putchar(toupper(ch));
//putchar : The value is internally converted to an unsigned char when written.
    i++;
}
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////
//LCase()

char *LCase(char *str)
{
char ch;
int i=0;

while(str[i])
{
    ch=str[i];
    putchar(tolower(ch));
    i++;
}
}
```

I finally write this . 
Although , I still not quite understand , but I learned

```
#include <ctype.h>
int tolower( int ch );
```

means tolower toupper can change only one character each time , so I can not

```
tolower ("This is a test of LCase");
```

code like this .