# Looping through an array with pointer notation

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm learning pointers in C++, while not as clear as I'd like to be on the subject, I'm slowly getting there.

My goal here was to write a function using pointer notation, to go through an array and change the case of the input.

For example

`("ab7d") myToUpper() -> AB7D`

Here is my idea for accomplishing this.

```
void myToUpperCase(const char *source, char *dest)
{
    for (int i = 0; *(source + i) != '\0'; i++)
    {
        *(dest + i) = toupper(* (source + i));
    }
}
```

**Results**

`("ab7d") myToUpper() -> AB7D\377`

Would someone mind explaining the reasoning behind `\377` being added to the output, obviously I'm looking for just the source to be changed here with nothing else added to the output.

Thanks

Comment: You're not null-terminating your output.

Comment: @KerrekSB would you mind explaining? I'm fairly new to C++.

Comment: Turn the `for` loop into a do-while loop..

Comment: why not using iterators and better..why not for_each and lambaded toupper?

Comment: Also beware of potential `toupper` UB. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805674/do-i-need-to-cast-to-unsigned-char-before-calling-toupper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are char arrays with a '\0' byte as a terminating character.

Your code is copying anything but the final '\0' byte.
So, if you chnage your code to terminate `dest` with a \0' byte all will be fine. (The '\377' you are observing just is the byte that happens to occur at that position in `dest`.)

eg. you could change your code to:

```
void myToUpperCase(const char *source, char *dest)
{
    for (int i = 0; ; i++)
    {
        if (*(source + i) == '\\0') 
        {
            *(dest + i) = *(source + i);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            *(dest + i) = toupper(* (source + i));
    }
}
```

You might also try another solution  without any index `i` based on :

```
while(*source++ = *dest++) /* empty body */;
```

(Purists (validly) might flag using side effects within loop conditions as bad smell! But it just should give an idea....)