# Is resolving char between signed and unsigned int unspecified?

Tags: c++, function, char, implicit-conversion, overload-resolution

It's my understanding that `char` may have a different underlying type depending on the architecture.
During implicit casting, an `unsigned char` may become and `int` or  an `unsigned int`.

[image]

Does that mean the following code has unspecified behaviour?

```
#include <iostream>

void function(unsigned int){
    std::cout << "unsigned\n";
}
void function(int){
    std::cout << "signed\n";
}

int main() {
    char c;
    function(c);
}
```

I don't get any compiler warnings.  Will it always resolve to "signed"?

Comment: As long as `sizeof int > sizeof char`, yes.

Comment: More accurately, as long as an `int` can represent every value that an `unsigned char` can.   A consequence of that, practically, is that `sizeof int > sizeof char (= 1)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I need to cast to unsigned char before calling toupper?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805674/do-i-need-to-cast-to-unsigned-char-before-calling-toupper)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your diagram is correct for the case of *integer promotion*. However, in the code `function(c)`, integer promotion does not happen. This is actually *overload resolution*.  If there were only one `function` then `c` is *converted* (not promoted) to the type of the parameter, whichever it is.

In the rules for overload resolution, if the argument could be made to match the parameter by integer promotion, then that function would be considered a better match than another function where *integer conversion* is required to match.

See Table 12 in C++14 (part of section 13.3.3.1.2) which lists the ranks of implicit conversion sequences for overload resolution.

So your code sample would call `function(unsigned int)` on a system with `CHAR_MAX > INT_MAX`.

However the sizes of types are *implementation-defined*, not *unspecified*.

Answer (score 1):

A `char` will almost always be converted to an `int`.  Whenever the `sizeof(int) > sizeof(char)` then a `char` will be promoted to an `int` regardless if it is signed or unsigned as like you said `int` can hold the entire range of `char`.

The only time you could get an `unsigned int` is when `sizeof(char) == sizeof(int)`.  In this case if `char` is unsigned then it would be converted to an `unsigned int` since `int` would not be able to hold the entire range of values.

This can happen as the standard only dictates that an `int` must have at least as much storage as a `char` so there could be some system that has 32 bit bytes and they make `char` and `int` the same size.

So this is **implementation defined behavior** as you need to know the implementation defined size of both types and the implementation defined signedness of `char` to know what will happen.

Answer (score -1):

This is just one kind of C++ feature, called "Implicit type conversion/automatic type conversion/coercion". when you pass a char to the function, the char was converted to signed int implicitly. Just like the code "int a = 'C';"  You can learn more about coercion from here:  http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/44-implicit-type-conversion-coercion/

Under the hood, all types are represented as binary number, So the type is just one way of explanation of the compile. There's no such mechanism you state above