# How to uppercase match in C++ regex_replace?

Tags: c++, regex, replace

I am looking for a simple way to turn C++ strings with underscores to camelCase, i.e.:
my_simple_humble_string
to
mySimpleHumbleString

Easy in Perl. I prefer not to use boost.

Comment: You can use `for loop`, check if a letter is an underscore: if yes delete the underscore and swap to uppercase (dont forget to change the length of the string -1), otherwise continue to next char.

Comment: boost's regex_replace supports format_perl

Answer (score 2):

According to [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refreplacecase.html), it is not supported. Could not find any other hints contradicting...

On the other hand, it is not too difficult to do it by hand:

```
std::string camelCase(std::string const& input)
{
    std::string s;
    s.reserve(input.length());
    bool isMakeUpper = false;
    for(char c : input)
    {
        if(c == '_')
        {
            isMakeUpper = true;
        }
        else if(isMakeUpper)
        {
            s += (char)toupper(c);
            isMakeUpper = false;
        }
        else
        {
            s += c;
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

**Edit:** in-place variant:

```
void camelCase(char* input)
{
    bool isMakeUpper = false;
    char* pos = input;
    for(char* c = input; *c; ++c)
    {
        if(*c == '_')
        {
            isMakeUpper = true;
        }
        else if(isMakeUpper)
        {
            *pos++ = toupper(*c);
            isMakeUpper = false;
        }
        else
        {
            *pos++ = *c;
        }
    }
    *pos = 0;
}
```

**Edit 2:** in-place variant for strings:

```
void camelCase(std::string& input)
{
    bool isMakeUpper = false;
    std::string::iterator pos = input.begin();
    for(char c : input)
    {
        if(c == '_')
        {
            isMakeUpper = true;
        }
        else if(isMakeUpper)
        {
            *pos++ = (char)toupper(c);
            isMakeUpper = false;
        }
        else
        {
            *pos++ = c;
        }
    }
    input.resize(pos - input.begin());
}
```

Comment: Upvoted, but in the first solution you should don't need the `std::stringstream` - it's only there to slow down your code. An `std::string` and `+=` instead of `<<` will do.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Updated - including reserving appropriate buffer size in advance...

Answer (score -1):

Regexes should be used sparingly, see ["Now you Have 2 Problems](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/223634/98845)

This is a good example of a case where they are not needed. Given `auto foo = "my_simple_humble_string"s` we can do:

```
auto count = 0;

for (auto read = 1; read < size(foo); ++read) {
    if (foo[read] == '_') {
        ++count;
        ++read;
        foo[read - count] = toupper(static_cast<unsigned char>(foo[read]));
    } else {
        foo[read - count] = foo[read];
    }
}
foo[size(foo) - count] = foo[size(foo)];
foo.resize(size(foo) - count);
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/qOHn8K)

A couple notes on the algorithm:

1. I will read from `foo[size(foo)]` which is undefined behavior prior to C++11: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at
2. I will not replace opening or closing underscores
3. I resize the string to match the length of the camel case string after converting which will invalidate iterators.

Comment: You probably meant something like `i = foo.find('_', i)` instead of `++i` (and initialization and beware that `std::string::npos + 1` overflows).

Comment: Even with the correction from Zerges, this solution is O(n*m) (with m being the number of underscores) for no reason, this is a transformation that can be easily done inplace in a single pass.

Comment: @Zereges Ugh, I didn't type the `if`. Note the range on my loop, I won't ever remove a leading or trailing underscore.

Comment: @MatteoItalia I would have thought this would run in *O(n)* time. What are you seeing that I don't?

Comment: Isn't `.erase` O(n)?

Comment: @melpomene Now that I look at it, I do believe that [you are correct](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/basic_string/erase/#complexity). We could certainly do this by copying... not my first inclination but I suppose it's doable.

Comment: @JonathanMee: yep, `.erase` - almost any time you have an `erase` of a vector or a string in a loop (unless it's at the end) it can be written more efficiently. As almost always happen, this can be written via the usual read pointer/write pointer loop (see @Aconcagua's second answer).

Comment: Now you have `std::toupper(static_cast<unsigned char>(foo[i]))` problems.

Comment: Now you are never incrementing `write`.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Ugh well that was just one debacle after another. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @JonathanMee: still broken `asd_def_ghi` => `ad_Df_Gi`. Also, how you set it up it wouldn't handle consecutive underscores.

Comment: @melpomene I don't think that was a problem. It was intentional: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21805674/2642059 But then I keep making mistakes on this answer... so who knows if I did it right.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Whew, now I know why Aconcagua switched to a `char*` for replacement. That was more complicated than I expected.

Comment: @JonathanMee: not really, you can use indexes or pointers, it's mostly the same. You just have to implement the basic algorithm correctly (which is mostly the same that is implemented by `std::remove`, for example).