# How to find out if there is any non ASCII character in a string with a file path

Tags: c++, string, unicode, utf-8, ascii

**Detect if there is any non-ASCII character in a file path**

I have a Unicode string with UTF-8 encoding that stores the file path, like, for instance, *C:\Users\myUser\Downloads\ü.pdf*. I have already checked that the string holds a correct file path in the local file system, but since I'm sending this string to a different process that supports only ASCII I need to figure out if that string contains any non-ASCII character.

How can I do that?

Comment: Convert to ASCII, convert back to UTF-8 then compare the original string with the one that has been converted twice.  If compare is successful send the ASCII string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As suggested by several comments and highlighted by @CrisLuengo answer, we can iterate the characters looking for any in the upper bit set ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fa7b646799f88c5b)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

bool isASCII (const std::string& s)
{
    return !std::any_of(s.begin(), s.end(), [](char c) { 
        return static_cast<unsigned char>(c) > 127; 
    });
}

int main()
{
    std::string s1 { "C:\\Users\\myUser\\Downloads\\Hello my friend.pdf" };   
    std::string s2 { "C:\\Users\\myUser\\Downloads\\ü.pdf" };

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << isASCII(s1) << "\n";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << isASCII(s2) << "\n";
}
```

> true
>
> false

Comment: Even though this may not be the solution, that function can be shortened to just `return std::all_of(filepath.begin(), filepath.end(), ::isprint);`

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805674/do-i-need-to-cast-to-unsigned-char-before-calling-toupper The casting is there to avoid undefined behavior due to a negative value, although in this particular case will never happen

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You're right, that would be shorter, but why this may not be the solution? A counterexample would be helpful.

Comment: Be aware that the behavior of `isprint` depends on the current C locale.  If someone changes the locale, this will no longer be doing a check for "printable ASCII."  At a minimum, I would change the name of the function to avoid confusion.

Comment: I would probably use something like `bool isASCII = std::all_of(filepath.begin(), filepath.end(), [](char c){ return static_cast<unsigned char>(c) <= 127; });` or `bool isASCII = !std::any_of(filepath.begin(), filepath.end(), [](char c){ return static_cast<unsigned char>(c) > 127; });`

Comment: So NUL,SOH **'\x01\02\x03"** are ASCII character per your code ?

Answer (score 9):

An ASCII character uses only the lower 7 bits of a `char` (values 0-127).  A non-ASCII Unicode character encoded in UTF-8 uses `char` elements that all have the upper bit set.  So, you can simply iterate the `char` elements seeing if any of them has a value above 127, eg:

```
bool containsOnlyASCII(const std::string& filePath) {
  for (auto c: filePath) {
    if (static_cast<unsigned char>(c) > 127) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

A note on the cast: `std::string` contains `char` elements. The standard doesn't define whether `char` is `signed` or `unsigned`. If it's `signed`, then we can cast it to `unsigned` in a well-defined way. The standard specifies exactly how this is done.