# Removing all empty elements in a vector from end

Tags: c++, string, vector

Given a `std::vector` of strings, what is the best way of removing all elements starting from the end that are empty (equal to empty string or whitespace). The removal of elements should stop when a non-empty element is found.

My current method, (work in progress) is something like:

```
while (Vec.size() > 0 && (Vec.back().size() == 0 || is_whitespace(Vec.back()))
{
    Vec.pop_back();
}
```

where `is_whitespace` returns a bool stating if a string is whitespace or not

I suspect that my method will resize the vector at each iteration and that is suboptimal. Maybe with some algorithm it is possible to do in one step.

> Input: { "A", "B", "   ", "D", "E", "  ", "",  "   " }
>
> Desired Output:  { "A", "B", "   ", "D", "E" }

Comment: Use `std::remove_if`

Comment: "I suspect that my method will resize the vector at each iteration " - no, it won't.

Comment: @keith No, the elements are already at the end.

Comment: @NeilButterworth `pop_back` does change the size, doesn't it?

Comment: @Baum Yes, of course it changes what the size() member will return, but it doesn't resize the vector's storage.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Maybe I'm assuming too much precision in OP's wording here, but they *are* talking about size, not capacity, strictly speaking.

Comment: I don't see that this question is a duplicate of the one linked above. I am asking to remove from the end, and remove_if seems to take forward iterators as arguments. An example using remove_if in this case would be helpful.

Comment: @Baum When a vector's storage actually  grows, we typically say it has been "resized", not "recapacitied", if that is a word.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE].

Comment: @JiveDadson What isn't MCV here?

Comment: remove_if() can be called with vector.rbegin() and vector.rend(). The choice of iterator is yours.

Comment: I don't know what to answer to that Jive Dadson, I am actually asking for that example. I have posted some code in order to show that I have tried something by my own before asking for help..

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow But `remove_if` will go over the whole vector, which isn't what OP needs here.

Comment: You could throw an exception to abort early. But I like the answerebelow better than using remove_if so lets leave it at that.

Answer (score 5):

As I did not find a good dupe on first glance, here is a simple solution:

```
// Helper function to see if string is all whitespace
// Can also be implemented as free-function for readablity and
// reusability of course
auto stringIsWhitespace = [](const auto &str)
{
    return std::all_of(
        begin(str), end(str), [](unsigned char c) { return std::isspace(c); });
};

// Find first non-whitespace string from the back
auto it = std::find_if_not(rbegin(Vec), rend(Vec), stringIsWhitespace);
// Erase from there to the end
Vec.erase(it.base(), end(Vec));
```

Note the `unsigned` in the lambda due to [this gotcha](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21805674/3002139).

[Live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Of9K30eo5EgiotJG) thanks to [@Killzone Kid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8746007/killzone-kid).

Comment: This is definitely a more modern C++ solution, but note that it does require iterating through the whitespace elements twice.

Comment: @MikeBorkland But on the other hand, we use a bulk-delete operation over repeated pops. Especially for simple stuff as `char`, I'm very reluctant to believe there is a non-negligible performance difference without benchmarks. That second "iteration" can be implemented as assignment to the vector's size member

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with vector of strings, which is as I understand OP's requirement

Comment: @KillzoneKid Ah right; his code tests chars not strings, went from there. Hang on, I'll fix it. Thanks.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Apart from missing closing brace for lambda, it still doesn't seem to work :( https://ideone.com/GJ202T

Comment: You are probably right. I'd be interested to see how they performed against each other with a `vector` of, say, 1 million elements, with 500,000 "whitespace" strings on the end.

Comment: @KillzoneKid Right, messed up what we wanted to keep and what to delete, the `find_if` is obviously wrong and should be `find_if_not`. Or switch the logic in the predicate, either works. Thanks again; not my day it seems.

Comment: @MikeBorkland Honestly, I wouldn't worry about it until I actually find it's a bottleneck in my real code. Clarity first, optimization later.

Comment: @BaummitAugen No worries, scratched my head as well ;) Have an upvote

Answer (score 4):

Here's a better way:

```
for (auto it = Vec.rbegin(); it != Vec.rend() && is_whitespace(*it); )
{
    it = Vec.erase(it);
}
```

It will start from the end and stop once non-whitespace has been encountered or the beginning of the vector is reached, whichever comes first. Note that I don't increment the iterator in the `for` loop.

Comment: Does `auto` pick the right iterator here? You need a delete iterator.

Comment: what is `is_whitespace`? Only API I find with that spelling is from the Rust language?!

Comment: also, `it = Vec.erase(it);` keeps on crashing with "error: no matching function for call" in both C++14 and C++17; what is this supposed to compile with?

Comment: `is_whitespace` returns a bool stating if a string is whitespace or not (custom function)