# Cant use the void func for converting string to Uppercase directly in if statement- c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have void func below:

```
void ToUppercase(std::string & data)
{
    transform(data.begin(), data.end(), data.begin(), (int(*)(int))toupper);
}
```

if i use if statement like this:

```
if (ToUppercase(str).find("AAA") != string::npos) // Do something;
```

It is showing me error "expression must be a class type". Why cant i use void func directly in if statement. Somehow, it is not feasible for me to return value from ToUppercase func.

Comment: Ask yourself: What does `ToUppercase(str)` return?  Can I call `find("AAA")` on that returned type?

Comment: No i am comparing find func with npos.

Comment: You're trying to call the method `find` on a `void`. This doesn't make sense

Comment: Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Once again relevant: [Do I need to cast to unsigned char before calling toupper?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21805674/3002139)

Answer (score 1):

`ToUppercase(str)` is, as you've declared, of type`void`. You cannot call member access operator (`.`) on void.

If you want to chain calls like this you could also return the passed reference

```
std::string & ToUppercase(std::string & data)
{
    transform(data.begin(), data.end(), data.begin(), (int(*)(int))toupper);
    return data;
}
```

If you insist on returning `void` for some reason, your only valid option of doing what you're doing is:

```
ToUUppercase(str);
if(str.find("AAA") != std::string::npos)
{
}
```

Comment: **Improvement**: the generic `std::find` will probably be faster than `std::string::find` (see the comment section of https://www.bfilipek.com/2018/07/string-view-perf.html)

Answer (score 1):

`find()` is a member method for the `std::string` class, but you are returning `void` instead.  Reform your code to return a `std::string` so that you can call `find()` on the return value.

Answer (score 0):

If your `ToUppercase` really cannot return the new string, you might try the following:

```
ToUppercase(str);
if (str.find("AAA") != string::npos)
{
  ..
}
```