# C Calculator Program with Stack

Tags: c, algorithm, stack, calculator

Hi I am completely stuck on this basic calculator. It runs almost perfectly but something goes wrong in the stack when I try inputting "5 / 5 + 9 * 2". The 1 from 5 / 5 seems to disappear when it is supposed to be addes to the 18 for the last loop. Happens for simular inputs like 2 * 2 - 9 / 2. Just need help finding this weird error that I have spent many hours trying to figure out with no luck! Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include<ctype.h>

struct StackNode
{
    char* data;
    struct StackNode* next;
};

struct StackNode* newNode(char* data)
{
    struct StackNode* stackNode =
    (struct StackNode*) malloc(sizeof(struct StackNode));
    stackNode->data = data;
    stackNode->next = NULL;
    return stackNode;
}

int isEmpty(struct StackNode *root)
{
    return !root;
}

void push(struct StackNode** root, char* data)
{
    struct StackNode* stackNode = newNode(data);
    stackNode->next = *root;
    *root = stackNode;
    printf("%s pushed to stack\n", data);
}

char* pop(struct StackNode** root)
{
    if (isEmpty(*root))
        return NULL;
    struct StackNode* temp = *root;
    *root = (*root)->next;
    char* popped = temp->data;
    free(temp);
    printf("Popped: %s\n", popped);
    return popped;
}

char* peek(struct StackNode* root)
{
    if (isEmpty(root))
        return NULL;
    return root->data;
}

char buffer[64];
char *ca = &buffer[0];
size_t size = 64;
int bufferIndex;
int first = 0;

int isWhiteSpace (char c) {
    if ((c == ' ') || (c == '\t') || (c == '\r')) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

char* getToken() {
    char* token = malloc(64);
    int i = 0;
    while ((isWhiteSpace(buffer[bufferIndex])) && bufferIndex <            strlen(buffer)-1) {
        bufferIndex++;
    }
    while (bufferIndex < strlen(buffer)-1) {
        int num = isWhiteSpace(buffer[bufferIndex]);
        if (num == 0) {
            token[i] = buffer[bufferIndex];
            i++;
            bufferIndex++;
            //printf("%s\n", token);
        }
        else {
            bufferIndex++;
            break;
        }
    }
    token[i] = '\0';
    first++;
    return token;
}

int main()  {
    while (1) {
        char* token = "test";
        char* postFix = "test";
       char* hold = malloc(64);
        postFix = malloc(64);
        int total = 0;
        int pres1 = 0;
        int pres2 = 0;
        struct StackNode* root = NULL;
    printf("Enter line: ");
    getline(&ca,&size,stdin);
    bufferIndex = 0;

    if ((strcmp(token, "quit") == 0)) {
        token = getToken();
        if (strcmp(token, "") == 0) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            printf("Too many arguments. Try again.\n");
            }
        }

else {
    while (strcmp(token, "") != 0) {
        token = getToken();
        //printf("%s\n", token);
        //printf("Top of stack: %s\n", peek(root));
         if (isdigit(*token) == 1) {
            strcat(postFix, token);
            strcat(postFix, " ");
            printf("%s\n", postFix);
        }
        else if (peek(root) == NULL) {
            push(&root, token);
        }
        else {
            printf("Peek: %s\n", peek(root));
            if (strcmp(token, "*") == 0) {
                pres1 = 2;
            }
            else if (strcmp(token, "/") == 0) {
                pres1 = 2;
            }
            else if (strcmp(token, "-") == 0) {
                pres1 = 1;
            }
            else if (strcmp(token, "+") == 0) {
                pres1 = 1;
            }
            else {
                pres1 = 0;
            }
            if (strcmp(peek(root), "*") == 0) {
                pres2 = 2;
            }
            else if (strcmp(peek(root), "/") == 0) {
                pres2 = 2;
            }
            else if (strcmp(peek(root), "-") == 0) {
                pres2 = 1;
            }
            else if (strcmp(peek(root), "+") == 0) {
                pres2 = 1;
            }

            while((peek(root) != NULL) && (pres2 > pres1)) {
                strcat(postFix, peek(root));
                strcat(postFix, " ");
                pop(&root);
                printf("Postfix: %s\n", postFix);
            }
            push(&root, token);
        }
    }
    do {
        //printf("Peek in DO/WHILE: %s\n", peek(root));
        strcat(postFix, peek(root));
        strcat(postFix, " ");
        pop(&root);
    } while ((peek(root) != NULL));
    printf("Postfix: %s\n", postFix);
    //ca = NULL;
    token = "1";
    bufferIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(postFix) + 1; i++) {
    buffer[i] = postFix[i];
    }
    //size = strlen(postFix)+1;
    //printf("TOKEN: %s\n", token);

    while (strcmp(token, "") != 0) {
        token = getToken();
        if (isdigit(*token) == 1) {
            //printf("--Token: %s\n", token);
            push(&root, token);
        }

        else {
            int operand1;
            //operand1 = malloc(64);
            int operand2;
            //total = malloc(64);
            printf("Peek: %s\n", peek(root));
            operand2 = atoi(peek(root));
            pop(&root);
            printf("Operand2: %d\n", operand2);
            if (strcmp(token, "") != 0) {
            printf("Peek: %s\n", peek(root));
            operand1 = atoi(peek(root));
            pop(&root);
            printf("Operand1: %d\n", operand1);
            printf("Token: %s\n", token);

            if (strcmp(token, "+") == 0) {
                total = operand1 + operand2;
            }
            else if (strcmp(token, "/") == 0) {
                total = operand1 / operand2;
            }
            else if (strcmp(token, "-") == 0) {
                total = operand1 - operand2;
            }
            else if (strcmp(token, "*") == 0) {
                total = operand1 * operand2;
            }
            sprintf(hold,"%d",total);
            //printf("Peek: %s\n", peek(root));
            push(&root, hold);
            //pop(&root);
            printf("Total: %d\n", total);
        }
            else {
                //printf("Peek: %s\n", peek(root));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
    printf("Total: %d\n", total);
}
    return 0;
}
```

I am supposed to/am using this as a reference for the assignment: http://condor.depaul.edu/ichu/csc415/notes/notes9/Infix.htm

Comment: You should not pass a non-malloc buffer to `getline`, since it will try to resize it if it needs more space.

Comment: `Postfix: / 5 5 + * 9 2` ? How is that postfix?

Comment: `bufferIndex < strlen(buffer)-1` is always true when `buffer[0] == 0`.  Better to use `bufferIndex + 1 < strlen(buffer)`.

Answer (score 1):

## isdigit() should only be tested for zeroness

Instead of:

```
if (isdigit(*token) == 1) {
```

use:

```
if (isdigit((unsigned char)*token)) {
```

## pointers make it easy to overwrite memory used elsewhere

The code does:

```
char* hold = malloc(64);
```

and then later on loops doing:

```
while (/* ... */) {
    // ...
    sprintf(hold,"%d",total);
    push(&root, hold);
    // ...
}
```

This causes all the values stored on the stack to share the same storage and to be overwritten whenever `hold` is changed.

The allocation must happen on every use:

```
char *hold;
// ...
while (/* ... */) {
    // ...
    hold = malloc(64);
    sprintf(hold,"%d",total);
    push(&root, hold);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Not only that, but of equal importance is to cast the argument to `unsigned char`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala `isdigit` expects a signed `int` argument.  The cast to `unsigned` seems to serve no purpose.

Comment: @TomKarzes on the contrary! " The header `<ctype.h>` declares several functions useful for classifying and mapping characters.198) In all cases the argument is an `int`, the value of which shall be representable as an `unsigned char` or shall equal the value of the macro `EOF`. **If the argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined.**" Now what's the value of `(char)'\x80'` on x86...

Comment: @TomKarzes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805674/do-i-need-to-cast-to-unsigned-char-before-calling-toupper-tolower-et-al

Comment: @jhnc I did as you suggested, however it did not change anything output wise and thus the problem that I am having is still happening.

Comment: Did you change both calls? There are two in your code.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I guess that makes sense, although in practice it will only make a difference if non-ascii characters are encountered.

Comment: @TomKarzes yes, that is true. For example my C code often has non-ascii characters whenever I accidentally hold the AltGr for a bit too long and hitting space bar...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala It looks like it's using the argument directly as a table index, without doing any range checks first.  I had assumed that any value outside of the desired range would simply return 0, but that does not appear to be the case.

Comment: @jhnc Yes, I changed both spots.

Comment: Ah, I just noticed that 5/5+9*2 isn't 36