# What's an alternate way of getting the char's int value to increment?

Tags: c, char, c-strings, string-literals, function-definition

While in the progress of making string functions, I have tried building a function somewhere similar to `strlwr()` which I named `lowercase()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *lowercase(char *text);

int main() {
    char *hello = "Hello, world!";
    printf("%s\n", lowercase(hello));
}

char *lowercase(char *text) {
    for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
        if (isalpha(text[i])) {
            (int) text[i] += ('a' - 'A');
            continue;
        } else if (text[i] == '\0') {
            break;
        }
    }
    return text;
}
```

I learned that the gap for a big letter and small letter would be 32, which is what I used. But then I got this error:

```
lowercase.c:14:13: error: assignment to cast is illegal, lvalue casts are not supported
            (int) text[i] += 32;
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~
```

I want to increment the value of the char if it is considered a letter from A-Z. Turns out I can't, since the char is in an array, and the way I'm doing it doesn't seem to make sense for the computer.

Q: **What alternate ways can I use to complete this function? Can you explain further why this error is like this?**

Comment: Do you want to convert it to `int`, increment it, then jam it back into `char`? If so: `text[i] = (int) text[i] + x`. Keep in mind this is just *begging* for seemingly bizarre overflow bugs because these two representations are significantly different.

Comment: Why not just `text[i] |= 32` and forget about the `int` conversion?

Comment: _Side note:_ As you have it, `hello` _points_ to a string constant [that is probabably loaded into R/O memory]. To allow this to work, do: `char hello[] = "Hello, world!";` Now, the _array_ of chars is on the stack (i.e. modifiable).

Comment: You are likely to run into **undefined behaviour** here, as you are trying to modify (*via* a pointer) a string literal's data (which the compiler is perfectly entitled to store in a read-only code section).

Comment: Don't hard code `32`.  If you're going to do it this way, please, for the sanity of future readers, write `'a' - 'A'`

Comment: @WilliamPursell Yeah, I tried some testing for `char` value before making the function, which is why I made this. Thank you for pointing out mistake I made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though in C string literals have types of non-constant character arrays nevertheless  you may not change string literals.

```
char *hello = "Hello, world!";
```

From the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 7 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
> elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to
> modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.**

So you should declare the identifier `hello` like a character array

```
char hello[] = "Hello, world!";
```

Within the function you should not use magic numbers like `32`. For example if the compiler uses the EBCDIC coding your function will produce a wrong result.

And in the loop instead of the type `int` you have to use the type `size_t` because an object of the type int can be unable to store all values of the type `size_t` that is the return type of the `sizeof` operator or of the function `strlen`.

This statement

```
(int) text[i] += 32;
```

does not make a sense because in the left side of the expression there is an rvalue due to the casting.

The function can be implemented the following way

```
char * lowercase( char *text ) 
{
    for ( char *p = text; *p; ++p ) 
    {
        if ( isalpha( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) 
        {
            *p = tolower( ( unsigned char )*p );
        } 
    }

    return text;
}
```

Comment: Please fix this, what you should've said was `tolower((unsigned char) *p)`.

Comment: @BPML Thanks. I was not attentive.

Comment: Why do you cast to `unsigned char`?

Comment: @JohnKugelman The argument of these functions shall be unsigned char. Otherwise due to the integer promotions you can get undefined behavior.

Comment: TIL. [Do I need to cast to unsigned char before calling toupper(), tolower(), et al.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805674/do-i-need-to-cast-to-unsigned-char-before-calling-toupper-tolower-et-al)

Comment: If you use `tolower()` the `isalpha()` check isn't needed. `tolower()` returns non-alphabetic characters unmodified.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I agree. It could be done without such a check.

Answer (score 1):

The cast is unnecessary. `char`s are integral types and can be incremented without fanfare:

```
text[i] += 32;
```

As several commenters have noted, you should also change your string to a modifiable string. `char *hello = "..."` declares a read-only string literal. Use array syntax to make it writable.

```
char hello[] = "Hello, world!";
```

You'll also want to switch `isalpha()` to `isupper()` so you only modify uppercase letters.

By the way, if you move the `else if` check into the `for` loop's test condition you can get rid of both the `break` and the `continue`.

```
for (int i = 0; text[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    if (isupper((unsigned char) text[i])) {
        text[i] += 32;
    }
}
```

Comment: Even shorter: `for ( unsigned char *p = text; *p; p++ ) *p = toupper( *p );`

Comment: @AndrewHenle There was a bug when BPML posted that comment that I've fixed.