# Passing argument 1 of 'toupper' makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: c, pointers, casting, string.h

This block of code is a simple "convert to uppercase" program but, when I compile, I get the error that is the title above. Any solutions?

```
char *input = argv[1];
printf("%s\n", input);
char toUpper = ("%s\n",toupper(input));
printf("%s\n", toUpper);
```

Comment: `char toUpper = ("%s\n",toupper(input));` Whats this supposed to be?

Comment: The argument to `toupper()` must be a single character. But `input` is a pointer to a character, not a character.

Comment: It looks like you have your `printf` code mixed in with the assignment to `toUpper`.

Comment: Are you trying to convert the whole argument to uppercase, or just the first character? If you want to convert the whole argument, you need to loop over the characters, since `toupper()` just works on one character at a time.

Comment: @Barmar I am trying to get the entire argument into a uppercase

Comment: @tkausl im very new to C so sorry about this, but it is supposed to store the string input as a uppercase version of it

Comment: You need to review the difference between strings and chars.

Answer (score -1):

toupper() does just one char (int).

 You need to do each char...

for (char *x=input, *x, x++) *x = toupper(*x);

That changed the string, so then print as before.

```
printf("%s\n", input);
```

Comment: Strictly speaking it should be `toupper((unsigned char)*x)`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805674/do-i-need-to-cast-to-unsigned-char-before-calling-toupper-tolower-et-al

Comment: @NateEldredge Even stricter, s/b `toupper(*(unsigned char *)x)`  to properly handle negative values encoded with the antiquated non-2's complement.