# Error: Ignoring return value of function declared with pure attribute

Tags: c, cs50

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Points assigned to each letter of the alphabet
int POINTS[] = { 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10 };

int compute_score(string word);

int main(void)
{
    // Get input words from both players
    string word1 = get_string("Player 1: ");
    string word2 = get_string("Player 2: ");

    // Score both words
    int score1 = compute_score(word1);
    int score2 = compute_score(word2);

    // TODO: Print the winner
    if (score1 > score2) {
        printf("Player 1 wins!\n");
    } else if (score2 > score1) {
        printf("Player 2 wins!\n");
    } else {
        printf("Tie!\n");
    }
}

int compute_score(string word)
{
    // TODO: Compute and return score for string
    int score = 0;

    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(word); i < n; i++) {
        if (isalpha(word[i])) {
            tolower(word[i]);
            score += POINTS[word[i] - 64];
        }
    }
    return score;
}
```

It seems to be saying there is something wrong with the return value of the `compute_score` function. I tried everything but don't know what is up. It says it is on line 38 character 13. I tried to comment out certain parts of the code but it still comes up with the same error.

Comment: Please provide the full and exact error message. Also provide any other warnings/messages that may be present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably, that message is coming from the `tolower(word[i]);` line – because you *are* ignoring the return value of the call to `tolower`. And you shouldn't be ignoring it, because it's the value you want to assign to `word[i]`.

The [`tolower` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/tolower) takes a (plain) `int` argument, which means it is **passed by value** (i.e. a *copy* is sent to the function) and the value of the variable in the calling function won't (can't) be changed.

Instead, the (possibly) modified (lowercase) character will be in the returned value that you are ignoring.

So, instead of the erroneous call you make, use this:

```c
word[i] = (char)tolower((unsigned char)word[i]);
```

(Many people will lazily ignore the two casts; but they really *should* be used: [Do I need to cast to unsigned char before calling toupper(), tolower(), et al.?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21805674/10871073.))

---

Also (though not related to your error message), the following line is highly suspicious:

```c
score += POINTS[word[i] - 64];
```

Using the ASCII character set, this will give the **1-based** index into your array for **uppercase** letters; lowercase letters will be virtually guaranteed to cause an out-of-bounds error accessing the `POINTS` array.

Don't use such "magic" numbers in your code. For a **zero-based** index using **lowercase** letters, use this:

```c
score += POINTS[word[i] - 'a'];
```

In fact, you can combine the two lines I have offered corrections for into one:

```c
score += POINTS[tolower((unsigned char)word[i]) - 'a'];
```