# Writing to a file in C segmentation Fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, file-conversion

I have a function that gets a string from the user and then does the following

```
void TraverseFile(char *inFile, char *outFile)
{
    FILE *pIn;
    FILE *pOut;
    pIn = fopen(inFile, "r");
    char c;
    if (pIn == NULL)
    {
        printf("File not found");
    }
    pOut = fopen(outFile, "w");
    if (pOut == NULL)
    {
        fclose(pIn);
        printf("The write file cannot be opened.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else{
        while(1) //while it is not the end of input file
        {
            c= putchar(tolower(fgetc(pIn)));
            if (feof(pIn)) break;
            fputc(c,pOut);
        }
        fclose(pOut);
    }
    fclose(pIn);
}
```

Two things are happening: the while loop is giving me a segmentation fault. I think after input is because fgetc() returns in an int and I want to convert to a char. And the creation of the second file has a weird dot next to the txt name (see picture).

[image: creation error]

Comment: What are `inFile` and `outFile`? Please post a [mre] that we can run ourselves.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is “while( !feof(file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong)

Comment: To answer your question: both inFile and outFile are string of a .txt file name. ie lower.txt containing information that is all uppercase requiring a conversion to lower case.

Comment: @AviBerger thank you that makes sense about the while(!feof(pIn). I have at the advisement put an if break with feof(). Yet I am still getting a segmentation fault. Is there anything that I am forgetting? I am new to C. Thank you for the help

Comment: `if (pIn == NULL)` is followed by an error message but the code just keeps going, eventually reaching `fclose(pIn);` or the other operations performed on it which could cause a crash. At least `pOut` failing to open is handled relatively well. You could easily run this in a debugger and narrow down exactly where it is crashing and why. If it crashes in code that isn't yours use the call stack to find your code where the problem starts.

Comment: @RetiredNinja the debugger was flagging a segmentation fault at the while initiation now it has moved to``` c=fgetc(pIN)``` yet, the creation of the output file uppper.txt still ahs the weird symbol after it

Comment: Since you have not shown where those filenames come from it's hard to say what the problem with them might be. Consider a [mcve].

Comment: `fgetc(pIn); ` actually returns an int, not a char (This lets it accommodate an out of band return value of EOF. Change c to be of type int and test it against EOF after calling fgetc. char can be signed or unsigned depending on platform. Your conversion of the result of getc to char and then its promotion to int (for the call to tolower) might be producing an illegal input to tolower resulting in an out of bounds array access in tolower which could be your segfault.

Comment: @AviBerger [Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73841887/writing-to-a-file-in-c-segmentation-fault/73842061#comment130387364_73841887) is correct.  OP's code risk UB.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, I was just playing with when that could occur. After checking further, it seems the conditions for this failure are a platform on which char is implemented as signed and there is an "extended" character in the file (i.e. outside of a 7 bit encoding). I had a different initial thought about how this could be produced that was wrong.

Comment: @AviBerger True: `tolower(x)` is is only specified for `int x` in the `unsigned char` range and `EOF`.  Else UB.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I need to cast to unsigned char before calling toupper(), tolower(), et al.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805674/do-i-need-to-cast-to-unsigned-char-before-calling-toupper-tolower-et-al)

Comment: `fgets` will leave the newline character at the end of the input, generally a bad thing for filenames. [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input) shows how to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least these problems

**Missing .h**

Add

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

**Wrong type**

`fgetc()` returns an `int` to handle the typical 257 different return values.  [@Avi Berger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73841887/writing-to-a-file-in-c-segmentation-fault/73842061#comment130387364_73841887)

```
// char c;
int c;
```

Using a `char` value that is negative and not `EOF` is undefined behavior with `tolower()`.  By saving in `int`, `c` will have a value in the `unsigned char` range or `EOF`.

**`while(!feof(pIn))` wrong**

[Why is “while( !feof(file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong)

```
int c;
while((c = fgetc(pIn)) != EOF) {
  c = tolower(c);
  fputc(c,pOut);
}
```

**Error lacks exit**

When `pIn == NULL`, no point in continuing. [@Retired Ninja](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73841887/writing-to-a-file-in-c-segmentation-fault/73842061#comment130387277_73841887)

```
if (pIn == NULL) {
  printf("File not found");
  exit(1); // Add
}
```

Without an early exit, `fclose(pIn);` is undefined behavior as `pIn==NULL`.

**Bad file name**

OP has "creation of the second file has a weird dot next to the txt name".  Certainly due to improper filename formation like insufficient buffer size for the name.

Comment: @autistic [cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805674/do-i-need-to-cast-to-unsigned-char-before-calling-toupper-tolower-et-al) not needed with `int c; ... c = fgetc(pIn) ...  c = tolower(c);`.  `c` is already in a valid range for `tolower(c)`.

Comment: @autistic OK. Post updated.