# Why predicate template argument inference works in some cases but not others?

Tags: c++, templates, type-inference, predicate

I have a class with a member function templated on a "predicate" type.  Until recently, the MSVC compiler accepted the following code, but now it says that it cannot infer the template argument for the predicate.

I suspected a compiler regression, but I tried clang (on Compiler Explorer), and it, too, says the predicate type cannot be inferred.

Why not?

Note that just wrapping `std::isalpha` solves the problem. I don't understand why.  Is there something special about the character classifiers?

```cpp
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>

int WrappedIsAlpha(int ch) { return std::isalpha(ch); }
int MyIsAlpha(int ch) {
    return ('A' <= ch && ch <= 'Z') ||
           ('a' <= ch && ch <= 'z');
}

class Foo {
    public:
        explicit Foo(char ch) : m_ch(ch) {}

        template <typename Predicate>
        bool Match(Predicate P) const {
            return P(m_ch) != 0;
        }

    private:
        char m_ch;
};

int main() {
    Foo foo('x');
    // The compiler is unable to infer the type for the Predicate
    // template parameter.  (MSVC used to be OK with it.)
    std::cout << foo.Match(std::isalpha) << std::endl;

    // Wrapping the function solves the problem.  Why/how?
    // Don't these have the same signature as `std::isalpha`?
    std::cout << foo.Match(WrappedIsAlpha) << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo.Match(MyIsAlpha) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[The above code compiles with x64 MSVC v19.37 (on Compiler Explorer), but the template argument inferencing fails for my local version 19.38.33133.  clang 17.0.1 (on Compiler Explorer) agrees with the newer version of MSVC.]

Comment: It could be that `isalpha` is a macro which would also cause an error.

Comment: c++20 says standard functions like these are not addressable. Basically whether it is implemented via a macro or a real function or some compiler magic is considered implementation detail and you should always use a wrapper for non-addressable standard functions. Also the signature for the wrapper is wrong, see cppreference for more details. Basically the argument must be `unsigned char`.

Comment: Strictly speaking, I think `foo.Match(std::isalpha)` is not allowed because the standard forbids taking address of functions in the `std` namespace, except for a very limited set of designated [addresable functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std#Addressing_restriction).

Comment: @WeijunZhou — `std::isalpha` takes an argument of type `int`; using the same type for the wrapper is appropriate.

Comment: @PeteBecker No, cppreference explicitly marks using a lambda that takes an int as "wrong".

Comment: Side note: Because of the [surprise covered in the notes here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha#Notes) you often don't want to call `isalpha` directly anyway.

Comment: @WeijunZhou That's not quite true. `isalpha` should also correctly handle the out-of-band information like EOF that might have been read.

Comment: It is not that much about  `isalpha` cannot hande EOF, it is that if the argument is not `EOF` and not representable in the range of `unsigned char` it is UB. If `char` is signed and you directly take an int, it may just be negative, hence UB. Also if `char` is signed and your argument casted to int happens to equal EOF, how can you tell it from the real EOF?

Comment: @WeijunZhou —`std::isalpha` takes an `int`, and writing a wrapper that takes an `int` changes nothing. It’s become fashionable to write belt-and-suspenders code that casts a `char` value to `unsigned char`, but for normal programs that makes no difference.  Ordinary character handling doesn’t produce negative values. And, no, the argument absolutely not be `unsigned char`; there is no guarantee that EOF will fit in an `unsigned char`.

Comment: It changes nothing only if at the beginning you are already calling it like `std::isalpha(static_cast<unsigned char>(ch))`, and that is the only correct way to call `isalpha` from `cctype` if `ch` is plain `char`. Like I said, it matters if `char` is signed, and `ch==EOF`. EOF cannot fit in `unsigned char` is exactly the point. I'm done here. You can certainly find a dup on SO addressing this. Or later if I have time I may write a full answer.

Comment: @WeijunZhou — nonsense. Calling that wrapper, which takes `int`, does **exactly the same thing** as calling `std::isalpha’, which takes `int`, directly.

Comment: Don’t “write a full answer” to prolong this discussion. The question is about why the code doesn’t compile, not about what you think is good style.

Comment: No.OP explicitly asks "Is there something special about the character classifiers?" in the body, and you have to cast it to `unsigned char` is one thing that is special about `cctype` functions. It is not minor detail. And yes, it is exactly the same as calling `std::isalpha` itself, but `std::isalpha(ch)` where `ch` is plain char and happens to be signed is outright wrong, not just bad practice. Period.

Comment: For your reference. https://stackoverflow.com/q/21805674/3966456. It is about `toupper`, but the same applies to all `cctype` functions.

Comment: I'm fully aware of the need to cast non-EOF values to unsigned char first.  I omitted that detail to try to keep the code focused on the compilation problem.

Answer (score 0):

[The first few comments identified the problem.  Since nobody posted an answer, I'll capture it here as a community answer.]

The standard restricts programs from taking the address of most functions in the std namespace.  @heapunderrun provided a link to cppreference.com's [summary of that restriction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std#Addressing_restriction), which I found especially helpful.

Many standard library functions are not necessarily implemented as actual functions.  They may be intrinsics or other forms of compiler magic.  That's why there's a restriction on taking the address of most of them.

I know some implementations of the C standard library implemented the character classification functions as macros.  Since macros cannot be in a namespace, I had assumed that the C++ standard library implemented them as functions.  That was not a reliable assumption.